# How to load jquery plugin on page load

Tags: jquery, plugins, load, slider

Im trying to use this page slider jquery plugin, you can see the demo here:

http://www.derekperez.com/jquery-pageslide/demo/

I can get it to work, but it works when you click a link. I would like to make it automatically run when they go to a certain page, is this possible? I am very new to this and searched google but couldnt find a solution.

Here is the jist from the demo above:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/pageslider/jquery.pageslide.js"></script>
```

<(link goes here, can only post 1 link) id="slide-modal">PageSlide as a modal element

$("#slide-modal").pageSlide({ width: "350px", direction: "left", modal: true });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do is on page load dynamically click your link using jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#slide-modal").pageSlide({ width: "350px", direction: "left", modal: true }); 
    $('#slide-modal').click();
});
```

That should make the script run on pageload.

Comment: Gah, you beat me to it by about 45 seconds. That's definitely the easiest way to do this.

Comment: @John - If this is the solution to your problem, you should accept the answer, so that someone searching on the same thing knows what worked for you.  :-)